# Unable to replicate ListAgg Join logic from SQL in PySpark - resulting in either hanging statement or Cartesian Join response

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following legacy SQL code that I'm attempting to migrate into PySpark as its current execution on our redshift clusters are causing significant delays, however I am unable to create  working replica of the specific script.

This is the SQL Script

```
 select pick_raw_cbrs_calc.*,
                   (select left(listagg(distinct warehouse_id, ','), 14) within group (order by main.vet_act desc)
                    from main
                    where pick_raw_cbrs_calc.vet_target between main.vet_act - (main.vet_act * 0.02) and main.vet_act + (main.vet_act * 0.02)
                      and pick_raw_cbrs_calc.bintype = main.bintype
                      and pick_raw_cbrs_calc.containertype = main.containertype
                      and pick_raw_cbrs_calc.operating_mode = main.operating_mode
                      and pick_raw_cbrs_calc.ranking_group = main.ranking_group
                      and pick_raw_cbrs_calc.fullness_type = main.fullness_type)   vet_bm_fcs
```

The aim of the code is to return the three "best" locations for a specific variable based on individual parameters.

I have written the following loop in PySpark to mirror the above code for all of the variables (there are a total of 10), however upon execution it either returns an error about Cartesian joins even though the join conditions are specific - or it never executes even after 12 hours on 15 G2.X instances in AWS Glue.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

import pyspark.sql.functions as f

from pyspark.sql import Window

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())


persons = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
             database="cbrs_benchmark_targets",
             table_name="cbrs_benchmark_targets")
persons = ResolveChoice.apply(persons, specs=[("scenario_id", "cast:long"),("fullness_coeff","cast:long")])

data = persons.toDF()

df1 = data

data_1 = data.alias("data_a")
data_2 = df1.alias("df1_a")

cond = ["data_a.bintype" == data_2.bintype, "data_a.containertype" == data_2.containertype,
        "data_a.operating_mode" == data_2.operating_mode, "data_a.ranking_grp" == data_2.ranking_grp,
       "data_a.fullness_type" == data_2.fullness_type]



for x in data_1.columns:
    if 'target' in x:
        act = x.replace('target','act')
        holder =  data_1.join(data_2, cond, "left")\
        .filter((data_1[x] > data_2[act]-(data_2[act]*0.02))&(data_1[x]< data_2[act]+(data_2[act]*0.02)))\
        .groupby(data_2[act], "df1_a.bintype", "df1_a.containertype", "df1_a.ranking_grp", "df1_a.fullness_type", "df1_a.operating_mode")\
        .agg(f.concat_ws(',',f.expr("sort_array(collect_set(df1_a.warehouse_id))warehouse_id")).alias("warehouse_id"))\
        .orderBy(data_2[act].asc()).select(act, "bintype", "containertype", "ranking_grp", "fullness_type", "operating_mode"
                                              , f.substring('warehouse_id', 1,14).alias(act+'_benchmark_fc'))
        print(x)
        data_1 = data_1.join(holder, cond, 'inner')

'''

I am unsure why this would return Cartesian joins when all join conditions are specified correctly and the code executes properly in Redshift - is there a better way to write this or am I missing something?
```

Comment: you see, the final `data_1` that is created will not have any alias. the alias is for the `data_1` that was created before the loop. so, if you provide that for join cond, it will try to join the first `data_1` columns rather than the loop's resulting `data_1`. wow, it's hard to explain this! a quick change will help you a lot - update the join condition to only use the column names since they're same across the 2 dfs. e.g. - `.df1.join(df2, df1.blah == df2.blah)` will result in the same join as `df1.join(df2,['blah'])`.

Comment: additional ups to my suggested change -- the former's result will have 2 columns with the name `blah` but the latter will have only 1 `blah` column post join.